# Google App Script onedit restrict to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to restrict an onEdit function to a specific cell (A1) in a specific sheet (Sheet1). So the code will only run when I make an edit in A1/Sheet1. My code below works for A1, but in all sheets.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = e.range
    Logger.log(range.getA1Notation())

    if(range.getA1Notation() == "A1"){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve the sheet name and the range using `e` of `onEdit(e)`.
- When `sheetName` and `range` are `"Sheet1"` and `"A1"`, respectively, the script of `// do something` is run.

#### Modified script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  var range = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (sheetName == "Sheet1" && range == "A1") {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Why `event.source.getActiveSheet` and not `event.range.getSheet`?

Comment: @Derek Morgan Thank you for your response.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your advice. And I'm sorry for my poor skill. Can I ask you about the difference of them? I would like to study about this.

Comment: They are fundamentally different methods, and the one which is used is dependent on your intent. Consider: `function onEdit(e) { Utilities.sleep(10000); Browser.msgBox(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() + "\n" + e.range.getSheet().getName()); }`

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you so much for your answer. I would like to use them. I could get a new knowledge.