# Run OnEdit only when edit is made to a specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All:

I am new... very new to coding, so I apologize that my coding probably makes people cringe.  I have a script that will show and hide sheets depending on the value of cells on a sheet called "Teacher Information."  The script is working great except it is running any time an edit is made to ANY of the sheets in the file.  I only want it to run if a change is made to the "Teacher Information" sheet.  Please advise.  Thank you for sharing your expertise.  Here is my current code:

```
function HideSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Teacher Information");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO1 Plan");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO1 Data");
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO1 Report");
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO2 Plan");
  var sheet6 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO2 Data");
  var sheet7 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO2 Report");
  var sheet8 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO 1 Plan");
  var sheet9 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO 1 Data");
  var sheet10 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO 1 Report");
  var sheet11 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO 2 Plan");
  var sheet12 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO 2 Data");
  var sheet13 = ss.getSheetByName("SGO 2 Report");

  var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('C22');
  var cell2 = sheet1.getRange('AJ22');

  if (cell1.getValue() == "") {
    sheet2.showSheet();
    sheet3.showSheet();
    sheet8.showSheet();
    sheet9.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "0") {
    sheet2.hideSheet();
    sheet3.hideSheet();
    sheet8.hideSheet();
    sheet9.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "1") {
    sheet2.showSheet();
    sheet3.showSheet();
    sheet8.hideSheet();
    sheet9.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "2") {
    sheet2.hideSheet();
    sheet3.hideSheet();
    sheet8.showSheet();
    sheet9.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell2.getValue() == "") {
    sheet5.showSheet();
    sheet6.showSheet();
    sheet11.showSheet();
    sheet12.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell2.getValue() == "0") {
    sheet5.hideSheet();
    sheet6.hideSheet();
    sheet11.hideSheet();
    sheet12.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell2.getValue() == "1") {
    sheet5.showSheet();
    sheet6.showSheet();
    sheet11.hideSheet();
    sheet12.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell2.getValue() == "2") {
    sheet5.hideSheet();
    sheet6.hideSheet();
    sheet11.showSheet();
    sheet12.showSheet();
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Script onedit restrict to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229093/google-app-script-onedit-restrict-to-sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say if this is an On edit trigger which could be done slightly differently but you could also do this.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
if( ss.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Teacher Information" ) return;
```

Comment: This worked... I have under 15, so I can't one up the response, but wanted to affirm that this worked... thank you.

Comment: @Mark Click the tick mark on the left of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the sheet name and proceed depending on that.

Something like this :

```
function HideSheets(e) {
   if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Teacher Information") {
       // If the sheet name is not equal to "Teacher Information" then Back Off..!!
       return
   }
   // Put your other codes below
   // More codes
}
```

This will check the sheet name before proceeding and if it's not equal to `"Teacher Information"` then it will return/break and not execute the code following it

Reference and further read : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit (as per techhowch comment, credits to him)