# I want to make it work only when "yes" or "no" appears in column 7

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If you enter anything in column 7.
This script works in column 6.

I want to make it work only when text "yes" or "no" appears in column 7.

How should I solve it? help me.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 

var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
var row        = activeCell.getRow();
if (col == 7 ) { // assuming status is in column 7, adapt if needed  
 sheet.getRange(row, col-1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM-dd-hh-mm');// change the display format to your preference here // 
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Script onedit restrict to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229093/google-app-script-onedit-restrict-to-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little different, but it solved.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var cell = activeCell.getValue()

 var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
var row        = activeCell.getRow();
//if (col == 7 ) { // assuming status is in column 7, adapt if needed  

if (cell == 'yes' ) {  
   sheet.getRange(row, col-1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/hh-mm');// change the display format to your preference here // 
}

else if (cell == 'no' ) {  
  sheet.getRange(row, col-1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/hh-mm');// change the display format to your preference here // 
}

}
```