# Google sheet "on form submit"

Tags: google-apps-script

My spreadsheet has two tabs and two forms (one for each tab). How do I restrict "on form submit" to only respond to one of the forms or one of the tabs?

I currently get the function to respond to any submission to either tab.

```
function updateOrders(){

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Edits');
let lr = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(lr,3,1,4).getValues();
let rn = sourceSheet.getRange(lr,2).getValue()-1000;
let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Orders');

targetSheet.getRange(rn,3,1,4).setValues(sourceRange);
}
```

Comment: e.range.getSheet()

Answer (score 0):

You have one spreadsheet that contains two sheets; each sheet is a linked response sheet for two distinct forms.

The solution is to use Event Objects ([ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)), specifically `range` (as mentioned by @Cooper). An IF statement, similar to that described in [Google App Script onedit restrict to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229348/1330560), will enable one to distiguish between a submission on one sheet or another.

Let's suppose that:

- the Response sheets(tabs) follow the normal pattern:

  - `Form responses 1` and `Form responses 2`
- you only want to respond to submissions to `Form responses 1`

  - you want to copy order details (in the form submission) to another sheet

---

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = e.range
  var editedsheet = range.getSheet()
  var editedsheetName = sheet.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the name of the active sheet is "+editedsheetName)
  // only respond to form submitssions on "Form responses 1"
  if (editedsheetName !== "Form responses 1"){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the form wasn't `Form responses 1`")
    return
  }
  // do something
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: do something becauise the form was `Form responses 1`")
  var editedrow = range.getRow()
  let sourceValues = sheet.getRange(editedrow,3,1,4).getValues();
  let rn = sheet.getRange(editedrow,2).getValue()-1000;
  let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
  targetSheet.getRange(rn,3,1,4).setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

---

- `e.range.getSheet().getName()`: returns the sheet name of the response sheet that received a submission
- `if (editedsheetName !== ){`: tests whether the response was on `Form responses 1`
- BTW: `e.range.getRow()`: returns the row on which the response was recorded.