# How do I block cells from editing based on a specific value in a different cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google work sheet where I would like to block the users ability to change rows in column AD if the value in column AC is 'N'. The reason I would like to use app script is because I already have a different data validation set for column AD.

I tried the code below but I keep getting a reading source error:

code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("working_sheet");
  var range = e.range;
  
  // Check if the edited column is AD
  if (range.getColumn() == 30 && sheet != null) {
    var acValue = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 29).getValue();
    if (acValue == "N") {
      // Prevent user from editing the cell in AD
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 30).setValue("");
      Browser.msgBox("Column AD value is 'N'");
    }
  }
}
```

Error I receive: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onEdit  @ Untitled.gs:2

Comment: You cannot run  these functions from the script editor without supplying the event object

Comment: On a tangent... it looks as though you are trying to check that the edit has taken place on a sheet named "working_sheet". No doubt there are many ways to do this, but I belive that @Tanaike 's solution in [Google App Script onedit restrict to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229348/1330560) reflects the most common approach.

Comment: `The reason I would like to use app script is because I already have a different data validation set for column AD` Would you please explain what you mean by a `different data validation set` and how this affects this script. Perhaps you mean that you have an _existing_ `onEdit` function/trigger. If that is the case, would you please provide details.